# Emulating the left mouse click with the help of xdotool and xbindkeys

Tags: xdotool, xbindkeys

I want to emulate the left mouse click with the help of [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdotool.1.html) and [xbindkeys](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xbindkeys.1.html) and have the following:

```
"xdotool 1"
    Alt+w
```

in ~/.xbindkeysrc;

the problem is that <kbd>Alt</kbd> also gets clicked in the process, emulating <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>left mouse click</kbd> instead. How do I prevent that?

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04, no virtualization.

Answer (score 2):

Are just just trying to emulate a left-click, or do you really need to use those programs? you can emulate 123 left clicks, with a 1-second delay between each, using nothing but xdotool by using:

```
xdotool click --delay 1000 --repeat 123 1
```

For 3 clicks with a 10-millisecond delay between each, use

```
xdotool click --delay 10 --repeat 3 1
```

The syntax is: `xdotool click --delay <delay in milliseconds> --repeat <amount of clicks> 1 <1 = left click, 2 = Right Click>`
So, for 1 left click, it would be: `xdotool click --delay 0 --repeat 1 1`
and for 1 right click, it would be: `xdotool click --delay 0 --repeat 1 2`